# How can I combine Quorum and Zero Knowledge Range Proofs

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I have 20 years of experience at java JEE coding, and 10 years in devops as well,
but no experience with blockchains, or the Go language.

I want to setup a cluster of Quorum blockchain nodes, including the features
provided in ING bank's zkproofs project. I want to be able to complete transactions where a Prover and Verifier can interact. The Github project provides zero knowledge range proofs
and zero knowledge set membership.

I don't think I'll have much problem bringing up Quorum, but the documentation in the github project https://github.com/ing-bank/zkproofs is limited! How can I come to understand how to put the zkrp code with the Quorum nodes, to realize an integrated system? Any tutorials that would help out there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Now there are a lot of interesting variants of Zero Knowledge Proofs with and without trusted setups. The traditional ZK SNARKS had a requirement for a trusted setup and demanded larger proof size and prover time and verifier times. However in the recent times Bullet Proofs have reduced the proof size significantly. ZK STARK is a recent Zero Knowledge Proof technique that has introduced transparent Zero Knowledge Proofs. Please find reference to two Zero Knowledge Proof based Toolsets implemented on JPMorgan Quorum protocol in the recent times.

[ZSL on QUORUM](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/zsl-q)

[Anonymous ZETHER](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/anonymous-zether)